# jquery animate slider onClick event

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I am creating a slider using jquery animate function. The first image is moving to left and is working fine.But the next image is not quickly following the first image. It displays a blank screen for a while. This is what I have tried so far:

```
$('.next').live('click',function() {
            $('.ac_bgimage').animate({
                left:"-80em"    
            }, 1500 , function(){
                test();
                });                
        });
        function test() {

        $('.ac_bgimage').attr('src','images/2.jpg');
        $('.ac_bgimage').css('left','0em');
    }
```

I am stuck at this point. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post what you have in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider/01.html) jquery plugin. This will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In your [jsfiddle.net/cSVWv](http://jsfiddle.net/cSVWv), you have two errors, because you have you div with 'next' class hidden, as thats is not possible to trigger the 'click' event. The other is, in image with 'ac_bgimage' class you need to the position relative to works.

See my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/tvaMK/

Comment: Thanks for replying i need continues image for that

Comment: as second image should starts along with first one